# How do I reference a javascript class in a different HTML's script class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm currently working with bootstrap and webpack on a website, alongside a discord bot that works off the discord.js API. My index.html has two buttons and I want one to run a command on the discord bot.

I've referenced a different .js file for my scripts in the index.html.

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

This handles my imports mainly scss files and my bootstrap. 
I also have a button in my HTML that looks like this.

```
<a href="#" id="robbery-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Robbery</a>
```

I tried using onclick events, however when compiling, I got the error "robbery not defined" when trying to use this syntax: `onclick="robbery()` "

I've tried writing a function called `robbery()` in the script file (app.js) however, it just doesn't seem to pick it up. I've also tried writing event listeners in js in app.js, nothing seems to work.

This is my first time writing a bootstrap website so I'm probably messing up somewhere, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Rather than using the inline attribute binders, you should be using the `addEventListener(event, eventHandler)` method instead.

Comment: I'm currently using this event listener ***document.getElementById("robbery-btn").addEventListener("click", robbery, false);*** And I think it's picking up correctly now.

Comment: So are you sure you js file is loaded and not a 404?

Comment: I'm now getting invalid regexp group as a syntex error.

Comment: impossible for us to know

Comment: Yeah I understand that, sorry for wasting your time